# Google App Engine unable to find dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, atom-editor

I started using [Atom](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/189) editor and inadvertently renamed everything in my google app engine folder from "appengine" to "google.golang.org". I switched it all back even replacing the "go_appengine" folder but I'm still getting the following error when I run my app:

```
goapp serve: unable to find dev_appserver.py
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using version control? Can you roll back?

Comment: I am using version control on my app but not the whole app engine platform and the problem seems with the platform

Comment: If it were me, I'd reinstall the SDK if that's what's been mangled. I would have less than 100% confidence in a repaired SDK even if it appeared to work fine.

Comment: Another thing to consider if you use the Google Cloud SDK.  Starting with release 0.9.68, it will no longer be distributing the stand alone App Engine SDK, which includes dev_appserver.py.  You can continue to use those scripts by installing the stand-alone App Engine SDK: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads.